# delayed CRUD operations, using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, delay, sqliteopenhelper

`my issue is that when I create or update recipes, those created and updated recipes would not display in the cookbook fragment unless I navigate to a different navigation tab like favourite or map using the bottom navigation bar, then navigate back to the Cookbook fragment.

to summarise: my issue is to do with refreshing or updating the data in the Cookbook fragment when a user adds or updates a recipe.

the classes I am using to handle the crud operations and display the list of recipes are CookbookFragment, CookbookAdapter, AddActivity, UpdateActivity, MyRecipe and RecipeDatabase:

#### CookbookFragment:

```
public class CookbookFragment extends Fragment implements CookbookAdapter.RecipeItemClickListener {

    private FragmentCookbookBinding binding;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton add_button;
    private CookbookAdapter adapter;
    private List<MyRecipe> recipes;

    private RecipeDatabase recipeDatabase;



    // this works public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                           //  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentCookbookBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        add_button = root.findViewById(R.id.add_button);


        // Set up RecyclerView and its adapter
        recipes = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CookbookAdapter(recipes, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Set up FAB click listener for adding a new recipe
        add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        recipeDatabase = new RecipeDatabase(requireContext());

        storeDataInArrays();
        

        return root;

    }

    void storeDataInArrays() {
        Log.d("CookbookFragment", "storeDataInArrays start");
        Cursor cursor = recipeDatabase.readAllData();
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String recipeTitle = cursor.getString(1);
                    String recipeIngredients = cursor.getString(2);
                    String recipeInstructions = cursor.getString(3);
                    int recipeTimeToCook = cursor.getInt(4);

                    // Create a MyRecipe object and add it to the recipes list
                    MyRecipe recipe = new MyRecipe(recipeTitle, recipeIngredients, recipeInstructions, recipeTimeToCook);
                    recipe.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                    recipes.add(recipe);


                }
                Log.d("CookbookFragment", "Number of recipes: " + recipes.size());

                Log.d("CookbookFragment", "Before notifyDataSetChanged(): " + recipes.size());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("CookbookFragment", "After notifyDataSetChanged(): " + recipes.size());
                // Notify the adapter of the data change
            }

            // Close the cursor to avoid memory leaks
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("CookbookFragment", "onResume called");
        // Check if data needs to be refreshed and refresh if necessary
        // Example: storeDataInArrays();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRecipeItemClick(MyRecipe recipe) {
        // Handle the click event, e.g., open UpdateActivity with the selected recipe
        Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), UpdateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("recipe", recipe);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void refreshData() {
        recipes.clear();
        storeDataInArrays();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

`

```
****CookbookAdpater class**
**
```

```
public class CookbookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CookbookAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public interface RecipeItemClickListener {
        void onRecipeItemClick(MyRecipe recipe);
    }
    private List<MyRecipe> recipes;
    private  RecipeItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    // Constructor to initialize the adapter with a list of recipes
    public CookbookAdapter(List<MyRecipe> recipes,  RecipeItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.recipes = recipes;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // ViewHolder class to hold references to the views within each item
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {
        // Declare your views here (e.g., TextViews, ImageViews, etc.)
        EditText editTextRecipeTitle;
        EditText editTextIngredients;
        EditText editTextInstructions;
        EditText editTextTimeToCook;
       // ImageView imageViewRecipe;
        Button buttonCreateRecipe;




        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            editTextRecipeTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextRecipeTitle);
            editTextIngredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextIngredients);
            editTextInstructions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextInstructions);
            editTextTimeToCook = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextTimeToCook);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            // Initialize your views here
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                itemClickListener.onRecipeItemClick(recipes.get(position));
            }
        }


        public void bind(MyRecipe recipe) {
            editTextRecipeTitle.setText(recipe.getTitle());
            editTextIngredients.setText(recipe.getIngredients());
            editTextInstructions.setText(recipe.getInstructions());
            editTextTimeToCook.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getTimeToCook()));


        }

    }

    // onCreateViewHolder to inflate the item layout and create the ViewHolder
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    // onBindViewHolder to bind data to the views within each item
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyRecipe recipe = recipes.get(position);
        Log.d("CookbookAdapter", "Binding recipe at position " + position + ": " + recipe.getTitle());

        // Log the contents of the recipe for additional verification
        Log.d("CookbookAdapter", "Title: " + recipe.getTitle());
        Log.d("CookbookAdapter", "Ingredients: " + recipe.getIngredients());
        Log.d("CookbookAdapter", "Instructions: " + recipe.getInstructions());
        Log.d("CookbookAdapter", "TimeToCook: " + recipe.getTimeToCook());
        holder.bind(recipe);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recipes.size();
    }
}
```

```
**RecipeDatabase class:**
```

```
public class RecipeDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recipe_database";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_recipes";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
    public static final String COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS = "instructions";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME_TO_COOK = "time_to_cook";
    
    
    public RecipeDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    
        String query =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_INGREDIENTS + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_TIME_TO_COOK + " INTEGER)";
    
        db.execSQL(query);
    
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    
    }
    
    public boolean addRecipeToDatabase(MyRecipe newRecipe) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    
        // Add recipe details to the ContentValues
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, newRecipe.getTitle());
        values.put(COLUMN_INGREDIENTS, newRecipe.getIngredients());
        values.put(COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS, newRecipe.getInstructions());
        values.put(COLUMN_TIME_TO_COOK, newRecipe.getTimeToCook());
    
        long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Log.d("RecipeDatabase", "addRecipeToDatabase: newRowId = " + newRowId);
        //db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    
        // Close the database
        newRecipe.setId(newRowId);
        db.close();
    
        return newRowId != -1;
        // }
    }
        public Cursor readAllData() {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    
            Cursor cursor = null;
            if (db != null) {
                cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    
            }
            return cursor;
    
    
        }
    
    public boolean updateRecipe(MyRecipe recipe) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    
        // Add updated recipe details to the ContentValues
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, recipe.getTitle());
        values.put(COLUMN_INGREDIENTS, recipe.getIngredients());
        values.put(COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS, recipe.getInstructions());
        values.put(COLUMN_TIME_TO_COOK, recipe.getTimeToCook());
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe.getId())}) > 0;
    
    }
    
    public void deleteOneRow(MyRecipe recipe){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe.getId())});
        db.close();
    
    }

}
```

````
```
````